# Why are tooltip values rounded?

Tags: vega-lite, altair

For some reason my tooltips are rounded to the nearest integer?

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the link to chart in the VL editor (version 3.0.0-rc14).

[(vega editor link)](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDuCWAmAXAFpAXGAzABmwGnCmQFNYBzZRdLXAiSAYwHsA7AM3OtAnsVkQA2xLpDatEAZVgAvYRgCMAVgC+dHpBYBXALYAjYgCcAYkwPaAhlQyQAdNjaQ19AM6IAnkK6EeUXeYMizjJyYABM2Kre6mSaCMQAtHyCIcCQAG7mApohkObO8A54UGIsksHUSpE+9DFx8QLm+gIiJWWyFSpRVerODJkpkH4s8AAK5vDwsCxkAJIsLIbU2DaKRYPmw2MTU2QA8pqIixjLKk5QQmTEw4FuekwCUu0KtFBJQialjyFKaw1NH21vqcorkAB6wZwiN7EAFfDq-RrEASw8oKVbnRECAAysG0-AquAihG6kHglnMIhY5m0OTJiHM8XgfkU2AYAA4-MRFAAWbBsgBs-N08mwxH5AHZ+ZhFPzsLo2cQGABOSAkiwGADW1EYsAMDE8akgV2Yk2mXh8kEQTHufAADtQANpRCCpdy2nIAR00GySllgaWEaw4SPg2uIoNtBmIziCAYWMdVZxdlrc7u1Xp9-D9AccxVgIe1DE0riYeOkftYqqiAF0zpBQVDU57vaUs3wc0H8wJQ9Zw5Ho7GrgPEyC3I209YM636e3A3mC9YiyWyxWWFWICSACS9EgWbWURC25xoAD0J4DZHMNjI-GQml0NlgTBPO+IFnPxEv9X4xHPoRs-J2DYABWziVoadJ5MQiCQhg3DqJBjLMqyHLmFyvICkKIpipK0qyvKioqhgTrVGAqQCLAugGP4Y7WAAgrmRoRlGMb+kOCbHGsS5WiufCVgo3Q+ORlHUQYtFQAAQoxfYsYO8awWAyzclxxY8TIq5LDY4qCTwwlUTR2oAMLScxA5sfJFQqcu6l8WuxxaTpyYUfpYnagAIiZ-asXGw72fyVlqeWtmadpSZkZAzmieJkAAKKebJ5m+YpAWljZT52WA8jKDWxIgMoQA)

```
{
  "width": 300,
  "height": 300,
  "config": {
    "title": {"fontSize": 15},
    "numberFormat": ".0f",
    "style": {
      "bar": {"size": 20},
      "guide-title": {"value": "asdf", "fontSize": 15},
      "guide-label": {"fontSize": 15}
    },
    "scale": {"bandPaddingInner": 0.5, "bandPaddingOuter": 0.5},
    "legend": {"symbolSize": 100, "titleFontSize": 15, "labelFontSize": 15},
    "axis": {"titleFontSize": 15, "labelFontSize": 15, "labelLimit": 1000}
  },
  "data": {"name": "data-dba50c8bae540866b10e6763560b8ec9"},
  "mark": "circle",
  "encoding": {
    "tooltip": [
      {"type": "quantitative", "field": "expressiveness"},
      {"type": "quantitative", "field": "customization"}
    ],
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "expressiveness"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "customization"}
  },
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.6.0.json",
  "datasets": {
    "data-dba50c8bae540866b10e6763560b8ec9": [
      {"library": "A", "expressiveness": 0, "customization": 1},
      {"library": "B", "expressiveness": 0.4, "customization": 0.7},
      {"library": "C", "expressiveness": 1, "customization": 0.7},
      {"library": "D", "expressiveness": 0.6, "customization": 0.7},
      {"library": "E", "expressiveness": 0, "customization": 1}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set `"numberFormat": ".0f"` in the config, and that's applied to the tooltip too.